# direct manipulation of image cache

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to directly manipulate the image cache as follows

1. create image data using canvas and store it in an Image object
2. somehow associate the Image object with a url such as "www.foo.com/bar.png"
3. setting the .src of any future Images to that url will use the cached version

I don't think this is possible but does anyone have any suggestions?

The closest I can think of is setting an attribute such as data-src instead and using a MutationObserver to intercept my fake url and set the image src that way.

Comment: The only way I could think of would be by sending that image data to the server first, so that it can respond with that same image data when `/bar.png` gets requested afterwards. And that would probably require to store the image data on the server (at least temporarily, like in a session), so that it can still respond with that same image data later on, should it be requested again, f.e. by a browser that doesn’t trust the cache and wants to get the image data again no matter what.

Comment: Who/what will be setting the image source to `/bar.png` later on? Can’t you see to it that at that time the data URI is used in the first place?

Comment: A little background maybe? Like that, I would say that no you can't do it. But why do you want to do it? There may be a workaround. Like on load, if the src is the aimed one, change its src to the wanted one.

Comment: I'm developing on a connected device that supports html5 but doesn't implement an image cache so I've implemented an indexeddb cache to store the most popular images which are dynamically fetched from the product catalogue, to reduce cdn bandwidth. The idea is to force those images into the cache each time the app boots up under their original urls just to try and make things seamless. I don't need to do it that way, of course, but it's partly experimentation.